# Select key from json inside array in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column called `props` that looks like this:

`{"house_color": "white", "dynamic_properties": [{ "visibility" : "blue" }, { "autonomy" : "self"}]}`

Right now I know how to get the all the colors for all of my houses by doing:

`select "props"->"house_color" as color 
 FROM houses`

Now, I'm trying to get all the visibility dynamic properties by doing some type of condition in the SELECT, and I'm stuck. So, in the example I would just get 'blue'. I'm looking for something like

`select "props"->"dynamic_properties"->"visibility" as color 
 FROM houses`

But I don't know how to look in within objects in that `dynamic_properties` array.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2c729613e5d022cfdf88944ce000a15d)

```
WITH jsondata AS (
    SELECT '{"house_color": "white", "dynamic_properties": [{ "visibility" : "blue" }, { "autonomy" : "self"}]}'::json as data
)
SELECT
    data ->> 'house_color'
FROM jsondata, json_array_elements(data -> 'dynamic_properties') as elem
WHERE elem ->> 'visibility' = 'blue'
```

`json_array_elements` expands the array into one row per element. So in your example the result are two rows. These rows can be filtered by its key/value pair.